# I Have a Basic ListView, but How to Link it to Activities?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I'm lost, so can I please have some help on how to link the list items to seperate activities? I have it to explain the different species available for what I am trying to do. It displays stuff such as dwarves, humans, all the fun stuff. Thanks in advance.

```
 package com.apw.games.rpg.medieval;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Species extends Activity {

  private ListView mainListView ;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.species);

    // Find the ListView resource. 
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Human", "Dwarf", "Earth-Born", "Elf",
                                  "Sky Spirit", "Water Spritit", "Death Spirit", "War Spirit"};  
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);

    // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String> 
    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items. 
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.
    listAdapter.add( "Troll- Coming Soon" );
    listAdapter.add( "Giant- Coming Soon" );
    listAdapter.add( "God- Coming Soon" );
    listAdapter.add( "Monster- Coming Soon" );

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setOnItemClickListener()` on your `ListView`, then call `startActivity()` from the `onItemClick()` method of that listener.

More often, though, you will find developers using `ListActivity`, instead of `Activity`, and overriding `onListItemClick()` in their `ListActivity`. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/List

Comment: @apw2012: Sometime after your call to `findViewById()`. I humbly suggest that you use a search engine to search on `setOnItemClickListener()`, so you can find sample code for its use. I do not have any such samples in my book, otherwise I would have pointed you to one.

Comment: I guess I'll use buttons instead. :(